# Html não renderiza valor de radio button

Tags: html

Preciso pegar o valor da `input` radio dentro de uma modal `bootstrap`, mas ele não renderiza o valor fica dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizei esse exemplo de radios:

```
<div id="itemList">
<input type="radio" value ="1" class="overWrite" name="overWrite"  />Yes
<input type="radio" value ="2" class="overWrite" name="overWrite"  />No 
</div>
```

No debug, percebi que quando pego o valor logo ao carregar a pagina desta forma:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

     var overwrite = $('#itemList input:radio:checked').val();

     alert('value = ' + overwrite);
  });
```

Ele consegue capturar o value da input, porém quando pego através do change ou click ele retorna vazio:

```
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function () {
    var radioValue = $(this).val();
    alert(radioValue);
});
```

Quando a modal é carregada na página a input radio perde seu value, no mesmo formulário existem outras inputs, mas isso acontece apenas com o radio button. Alguém sabe por quê?

Comment: Provavelmente esse 'value' está sendo setado dinamicamente para vazio, por isso quando você acaba de carregar o documento ele está lá e quando puxa pelo 'click' ele já não está mais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As inputs do tipo `radio` são melhores utilizada para a submissão de um formulário, pois o `name` de ambas devem ser iguais.

Para pagar o valor de modo dinâmico, o melhor jeito é utilizar a tag `select`, ela substitui o `input radio` e resolve os problemas.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <select id="option">
      <option value="Yes">Sim</option>
      <option value="No">Não</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('option').value);">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isso não é uma solução do problema, alem de que, dependendo do sistema, piora a usabilidade, uma vez que com "Select" serão necessários 2 clicks para para selecionar uma opção.

Comment: @Jhonnyjks, não acho que pioraria a usabilidade, pelo contrário, dependendo da utilização, pode facilitar tanto a vida do desenvolvedor quanto a vida do usuário (relativo à situação), pra mim, a resposta é válida como solução do problema já que o código está funcional e atende os requisitos do autor do post, somente falta o mesmo fazer as adaptações necessárias.

Comment: @VictorGomes, se o usuário terá que dar 2 clicks onde teria apenas 1, a usabilidade piorou! Não sou eu quem diz isso, é o estudo. Mais clicks/toques, menos usabilidade. O fato de o autor ter considerado a resposta como "melhor resposta" não faz dela a solução para o problema, somente a melhor resposta, onde o autor deixará de lado o problema para fazer de forma diferente.

Comment: @Jhonnyjks, mesmo que aumenta a "1" click durante o processo, deve-se olhar a viabilidade, para se trabalhar com `input radio` de forma dinâmica (como o caso do código acima), pode aparecer alguns problemas. É por isso que em html existem diversos outros componentes que no final são a mesma coisa `input button` e `button`, `meter` e `progress`, etc.

Comment: Hey @BrumazziD.B., pode sim haver elementos melhores, porém esse elemento da resposta não é um desses! Se você por qualquer outro elemento que também necessite apenas de 1 click, eu jamais vou alegar que não é um bom meio para o fim.